# access jquery validator error massage without accessign the input value

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin. I want to style the error massages thrown by the plugin without styling the value of the input field. I try and search a lot in varies resources. And I try the combination selectors. Unfortunately I didn't get the solution.
I use this code to style the error massage

```
.error{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
label.error{
//write style here
}
```

because the massage from jQruery validator coming in the label tag.